# Uninstall Xampp (Windows 7)

Tags: xampp

I have some problems to access phpMyAdmin (Access denied) so I think that my XAMPP was not installed correctly. I want to uninstall this programm but I don't know how. I don't find the uninstall file in my C:/xampp, I don't find the programm in CCleaner, and I don't find the programm in the uninstall panel of Windows. It seems that the programm doesn't exist but I can run it and access localhost. So I don't know what to do, please help !

Answer (score 1):

According to Xamp documentation :

> If you installed XAMPP using the installer version, please use the Uninstaller. The Uninstaller will delete all XAMPP entries from your registry and it will uninstall some installed services included with XAMPP. We highly recommend that you use the Uninstall program for removing XAMPP installations from the Installer version.Please backup all the data you want to keep before uninstalling XAMPP.
>
> If you installed XAMPP using the ZIP and 7zip versions, shut down all XAMPP servers and exit all panels. If you installed any services, uninstall and shut them down too. Now simply delete the entire folder where XAMPP is installed. There are no registry entries and no environment variables to clean up.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I know but I don't find the Uninstaller and if I try to uninstall each service, it doesn't work :/

Comment: So what happens when you go through your C Drive and try to delete them manually?